# add soundcloud rss feed to wordpress page

Tags: wordpress, soundcloud

Perhaps not the correct forum but Im hoping for some help with adding a soundcloud channel rss feed onto a new page on a wordpress site. I have tried a number of rss feed aggregators and added the relevant short code to the page but it still wont show the individual tracks on the page. I am looking to have them render the same as they would if embedded in a post.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A quick and hacky way could be something like this, you need to add this script to a page or modify a template, page - depending on your setup.

I would add a loop as well.

Hope this helps you.

```
$(function(){
        url = 'http://feeds.soundcloud.com/users/soundcloud:users:46971334/sounds.rss';
        $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: document.location.protocol + '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=1000&callback=?&q=' + encodeURIComponent(url),
        dataType: 'json',
        error: function(){
            alert('Unable to load feed, Incorrect path or invalid feed');
        },
        success: function(xml){
            values = xml.responseData.feed.entries;

            $('#feeditems').append('<iframe width="300" height="300" scrolling="no" frameborder="no"                                   src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=' + values[0].link + '&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;visual=true"></iframe>');

 $('#feeditems').append('<br/>');

 $('#feeditems').append('<iframe width="300" height="300" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=' + values[1].link + '&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;visual=true"></iframe>');

        }
    });
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/iambnz/WC5Q9/